# FireMonkey/Rad Studio XE2: How can I show the SaveDialog filter on OS X?

Tags: macos, delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FireMonkey/Rad Studio XE2: How can I show the SaveDialog filter on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977734/firemonkey-rad-studio-xe2-how-can-i-show-the-savedialog-filter-on-os-x)

I created an (Delphi XE2) Firemonkey sample program which contains a TButton and a TSavedialog with two different filters. (The TSaveDialog component supports the Win32/Win64 and OS X platform.)

It works fine on Win32/Win64, but I don't now why it does not show the Savedialog filters on OS X (VirtualBox/OS X 10.7.x).

How can I get it to work on OS X ?

```
procedure TForm1.Button_SaveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SaveDialog.Filter:='Format_1 (*.fmt1)|*.fmt1|Format_2 (*.fmt2)|*.fmt2';

  If Savedialog.Execute Then ShowMessage(SaveDialog.FileName+#13+'Selected filterindex: '+Inttostr(SaveDialog.FilterIndex));
end;
```